# Remove sonar lint issue from java stream

Tags: java

I have below code which is sorting based on data

```
creditDetailsDTO.getSectionDetails().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(dto -> DateUtil.convertToTxnDate(dto.getStartDate())));
```

Above code sorting data from `creditDetailsDTO.getSectionDetails()` this list based on `dto.getStartDate()`

Code is working fine only sonar issue is saying

> Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used.

How to resolved that??

Comment: You have no terminal operation in your pipeline. What is this stream supposed to do (what's the result you want from it)?

Comment: `.sorted()` sorts the elements in the stream, not the underlying collection you're streaming from. If you want to actually do something with the sorted data then you need to collect and assign it to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is effectively "dead code."

It configures a pipeline, but never invokes it, and it doesn't attempt to assign the result (which is a `Stream`) anywhere so that it could be invoked later.

If truly your "code is working fine", you could delete this statement and your code will still work fine, since it does nothing.

But, if you are trying to get your "section details" in sorted order, you'll want to collect them to a list, like this:

```
List<SectionDetail> details = creditDetailsDTO.getSectionDetails().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(dto -> DateUtil.convertToTxnDate(dto.getStartDate())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `collect()` call at the end is a "terminal operation" that actually causes the pipeline to be invoked. If you read [the documentation on `Stream`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) you'll see that some methods are "intermediate operations." These (and only these) methods return some type of stream with its configuration altered, but without actually invoking the pipeline. The other methods are terminal operations.